# GIMP Script-Fu: batch edit images with a mask

Tags: mask, gimp, script-fu, gimpfu

I have thousand of images that i must removed nearly 1/2 the content from.

Mannually i would:

- load image-a
- add alpha-channel
- import layer image-b (pre-made mask)
- make selection from masked out section
- delete mask layer
- clear selection from image a
- export image

Here is the code i have written in an attempt to automate this:

```
(define  (script-fu-auto-mask-image Mask InImage OutImage)
  (let* (
      Image (car (file-tiff-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE InImage InImage)) ImgW (car (gimp-image-width Image)) ImgH (car (gimp-image-height Image))
      PrimeLayer (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer Image))
      (gimp-layer-add-alpha PrimeLayer))
      (gimp-layer-new Image ImgW ImgH RGB-IMAGE MaskLayer 0 LAYER-MODE-NORMAL)
      (gimp-file-load-layer RUN-NONINTERACTIVE Image Mask)
      (gimp-image-set-active-layer Image MaskLayer)
      (gimp-image-select-color mask CHANNEL-OP-ADD drawable (0 0 0))
      (gimp-image-set-active-layer Image PrimeLayer)
      ;(gimp-edit-clear drawable)
      (gimp-drawable-edit-clear drawable)
      (gimp-image-remove-layer Image MaskLayer)
      (file-png-save-defaults RUN-NONINTERACTIVE Image drawable OutImage OutImage)
    )
  (gimp-displays-flush)
  (gimp-quit TRUE)
)
```

This is the terminal command i use to launch things and the feed back

```
gimp -i -c -b script-fu-auto-mask-image  "Pictures/test/mask.png" "Pictures/test/DSC00805.tif" "test.png"
bps: 16
load_contiguous
bytes_per_pixel: 6, format: 6
batch command executed successfully
```

It freezes then i must ctrl+c

i have tried below in the GIMP console:

```
(file-tiff-load RUN-INTERACTIVE "Pictures/test/DSC00805.tif" "Pictures/test/DSC00805.tif")
```

it returns (1) then i can see that it never actually loads the image in the status bar at the bottom of GIMPS window.

Im on Ubuntu 20.04 GIMP 2.10.18 (apt not SNAP)
i tried running GIMP from a Flatpak but was getting issues with GTK modules not loading ... anyway

literally an help would be appreciated - even alternative solutions if viable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's freezing because you've told gimp to start, but not told it to stop.

you need to encapsulate your existing command and then add -b '(gimp-quit 0)'

i.e.

```
gimp -i -c -b '(script-fu-auto-mask-image  "Pictures/test/mask.png" "Pictures/test/DSC00805.tif" "test.png")' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

Comment: Thank you, this was correct but i also have other issues in my script that i am yet to understand